# No puedo guardar archivo App.js usando react

Tags: reactjs, vscode

estoy aprendiendo react.js. Estoy utilizando vscode en un macbook air. Al intentar guardar App.js me da un error y me pide que lo guarde como sudo, y al darle que me lo guarde como sudo me sale este error:

> Failed to save 'App.js': Command failed: "/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code" --file-write "/Users/miguelflorez/Library/Application Support/Code/code-elevated-ngzymm" "/Users/miguelflorez/Desktop/myProjects/react/aprendiendoreact/src/App.js" Error using --file-write: EPERM: operation not permitted, open '/Users/miguelflorez/Desktop/myProjects/react/aprendiendoreact/src/App.js'

Answer (score 0):

Parece un problema de permisos, podrías intentar algo como:

```sh
sudo chmod -R ugo+rw /Users/miguelflorez/Desktop/myProjects/react/aprendiendoreact/
```

Desde una terminal, te pedirá tu contraseña.